# CGWindowsListCopyWindowInfo API is not listing down all the window names in 10.15 Catalina Beta version

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

We use the API `CGWindowsListCopyWindowInfo` to get the application window details. we are consuming the details like window name, path etc. This used to work till Mojave version but not working on 10.15 Beta (Catalina) version.

Please suggests how to achieve the required behavior using this API or if any alternative to solve this issue.

We tried few suggestions found on google but they didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I tried using applescripts to get window titles along with their process Ids. it worked but it requires app(executing applescript) to be added in "Privacy" tab under "Accessibility" option.

Comment: Is there any programmatic way to solve this issue? any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!